# Cut same shape out several times in photoshop image

Tags: adobe-photoshop-elements

How do I define a rectangle and then cut the same size several places on an image?

Answer (score 2):

Select the rectangular marquee tool, then change the `Style` to `Fixed Size`. You should now be able to use the `Width` and `Height` boxes and fill in a set size.

Now, every time you make a rectangle it'll be the same size.

[image]